# How to access a module into another module of Android

Tags: android, variant, android-module

I'm having few different variants and for each variant I'm having different module into my project but now I got a new requirement where I'll have to use an existing module in a new build variant. It means if any changes happen in code of `variant1` the changes should be reflected in the apps of `variant1` and `variant3`. Hope my query is clear.
[image]

In above image,

1. main is the common module for each type of variant
2. verify is the module which is completely different
3. wallet is the module what I want to use in a new module i.e. `companion`

Please guide me if there is a good solution to use it. Currently I'm copying whole files of wallet into companion which is not feasible solution for future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let's assume we have `moduleA` and `moduleB`, to access `moduleB` inside of `moduleA` add  `implementation project(":moduleB")` to `moduleA` `build.gradle` file.

Note that all files inside `moduleB` will be available to `moduleA` but files inside `moduleA` aren't available to `moduleB`

be sure to declare your modules in settings.gradle

`include ':moduleA'`

`include ':moduleB'`